# Finding the max of value of Map<id, sObject> based on custom field

Tags: apex, list, sort

I am trying to find the biggest record in the Map for each iteration. The sorting should be based on the custom field X. After finding the biggest record, I should increment one of its fields (Y field) by one and at the same time I should decrement the field X by one. For each iteration of the main loop, I have to find the biggest record among values of Map. However, when tried to come up with the approach below. It is giving all the values (1+) to one record only. What can be the problem? Any help is appreciated! Thank you. I will attach my code below for your reference.

```
        String var_curDPMId = dpm.Id;
        Integer varOP_RecommendedFT_MH = Integer.valueOf(dpm.BM_DPM_OP_RcmndedNumbOfPpl__c);

        Map<Id, BM_HourlyProductivityManagement__c> mapAllHPM = new Map<Id, BM_HourlyProductivityManagement__c>();
        for(BM_HourlyProductivityManagement__c hpm : [SELECT Id, Name, OP_IdleMHCalc__c, BreakTimeMH__c, Helper_OP_IdleMHCalc__c
                                                      FROM BM_HourlyProductivityManagement__c
                                                      WHERE BM_HO_ProductivityManagement__c = :var_curDPMId 
                                                      AND BM_HO_Slot__c IN (9, 10, 11, 12, 13)]){
                                                                                                                        
        if(!mapAllHPM.containsKey(hpm.id)){
            mapAllHPM.put(hpm.id, hpm);                                                  
         }                                                             
     }
        
        for(BM_HourlyProductivityManagement__c hpm : mapAllHPM.values()){
              hpm.BreakTimeMH__c = 0;
              hpm.Helper_OP_IdleMHCalc__c = hpm.OP_IdleMHCalc__c;
        }
        
        for(Integer i = 0; i<varOP_RecommendedFT_MH; i++){
            
        Decimal greatestIdle_Num = 0;
        String greatestIdle_HPMId;
            
            for(ID key :mapAllHPM.keyset()){
                // Here we can check if the current field value is greater or not if greater will update the dummy var with new value and the Id as well 
                if(greatestIdle_Num < mapAllHPM.get(key).Helper_OP_IdleMHCalc__c)
                    greatestIdle_Num = mapAllHPM.get(key).Helper_OP_IdleMHCalc__c;
                    greatestIdle_HPMId = mapAllHPM.get(key).Id;
            }

            mapAllHPM.get(greatestIdle_HPMId).BreakTimeMH__c =  mapAllHPM.get(greatestIdle_HPMId).BreakTimeMH__c + 1;
            mapAllHPM.get(greatestIdle_HPMId).Helper_OP_IdleMHCalc__c =  mapAllHPM.get(greatestIdle_HPMId).Helper_OP_IdleMHCalc__c - 1;

        }   
        
        update mapAllHPM.values();
```

Comment: You can simplify the logic by adding `order by Helper_OP_IdleMHCalc__c desc` to the original query (and keeping the query results in a list) assuming that field supports ordering. Then the biggest record will always be the index 0 one.

Comment: Thanks Keith. The thing is Helper_OP_IdleMHCalc__c  comes null in the beginning. I am using this field for the roll-up.

Comment: If it is null, what behaviour do you expect that isn't helped by ordering like KeithC said?